# Sublime: what plugin is putting that next in my status bar?

Tags: sublimetext2

The status bar in my sublime text editor says:

```
git branch: fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
```

How can I determine which plugin is generating  that text?

Comment: I hate to be that guy but... maybe it's git?

Comment: Since you have the exact text of the message, you could do a grep in your packages directory for that text.  That would definitely identify the culprit.  On windows the packages directory is usually `c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages`.

Comment: On Linux it's `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages` and on OSX it's `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages` (spaces escaped for your pleasure)

Comment: @kingdamian42 Yeah, in this case it's git, but I was curious about the more general strategy for identifying which package is adding text to the status bar.